# static constexpr method implementation causes gcc bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc4, constexpr

Here is a piece of code:

```
class Class
{
    static constexpr int getBug();
};

constexpr int Class::getBug()
{
    return 0;
}
```

What I basically do is declaring a `static` `constepxr` method in class declaration, then I implement it.

The original code was split in two file, and contained more methods / attributes which have been stripped, leaving only the required code.

When I compile the code I get the following error from GCC 4.6.0 :

```
Class.cpp:6:29: internal compiler error: in merge_types, at cp/typeck.c:825
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
```

1. **Is this really a bug?**
2. **In that case, what must I provide my report with?**

---

I've tested the code on an [online C++0x compiler](https://ideone.com/H7Zbz) and get the following error:

```
prog.cpp:3:33: error: the 'constexpr' specifier cannot be used in a function declaration that is not a definition
prog.cpp:6:29: error: a constexpr function cannot be defined outside of its class
```

This compiler uses GCC 4.5.1.
It let me know that my code is ill-formed, but introduce more question:

1. **Why does GCC 4.5.1 give an error and GCC 4.6.0 report a bug?**

---

After writing the last paragraph, I tested back on GCC 4.6.0 stripping the `static` keyword and the separate implementation compiles without any warning!

1. **Why do two compiler *of the same family* behave so differently?**

I know that `constexpr` methods should avoid any statement different to `return`, which may explain the GCC 4.5.1 error reporting.
As my method uses macro condition to return the good (constant) value, it takes a couple of line which explains why I want to use separated implementation (in addition to the usual recommendation).

---

My configuration:

```
Mac OS X.7
GCC 4.6.0
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin10.7.0
Configured with: ./configure
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mmacosx-version-min=10.7.0' '-v' '-save-temps' '-std=c++0x' '-c' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=core2'
```

Comment: In internal compiler error is *always* a problem, since it's a bug in the compiler. See if it's already been reported, and submit it if not. There are plenty of bugs in GCC pertaining to new C++11 features, so this is by no means surprising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `constexpr` is a new feature of the language, and according to the [C++0x Support in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) page, the support for this feature was first added to GCC in 4.6.  My suspicion is that it is in fact a bug in the compiler, that could be fixed in 4.6.1 or later.

GCC 4.5.2 generates an error because the feature isn't yet available in that version.  In fact, if you were to check the standard library headers for 4.5.2, you would see that all of the `constexpr` methods (as dictated by the standard) say something like 'Needs constexpr'.